# Update and Insert to a remote server (Linked Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to run a update and if the record does not exist on the remote server insert it.  I've tried 2 different methods (Get the output from the update and store it in a temp table and MERGE).  Below is the code I've used in both methods.

Here is the OUTPUT way I tried:

```
DECLARE @updated_ids TABLE(id nvarchar(255))
UPDATE DBSERVER.ft_test2.dbo.TestOrders SET OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber, FormulaCode=o.FormulaCode, FormulaName=o.FormulaName, BeginDate=o.BeginDeliveryDate
OUTPUT inserted.OrderNumber INTO @updated_ids
FROM DBSERVER.ft_test2.dbo.TestOrders ta, LTB.dbo.Orders o
WHERE ta.OrderNumber=o.OrderNumber AND o.BeginDeliveryDate >= '12/24/15'
INSERT INTO DBSERVER.ft_test2.dbo.TestOrders
SELECT o.OrderNumber, o.FormulaCode, o.FormulaName, o.BeginDeliveryDate
FROM LTB.dbo.Orders o
WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @updated_ids) AND o.BeginDeliveryDate >= '12/24/15'
GO
```

The error I get is:

```
Msg 405, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
A remote table cannot be used as a DML target in a statement which includes an OUTPUT clause or a nested DML statement.
```

The MERGE that I tried was:

```
MERGE
INTO DBSERVER.ft_test2.dbo.TestOrders ta
USING LTB.dbo.Orders o
ON ta.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
WHEN MATCHED AND o.BeginDeliveryDate >= '12/24/15' AND (o.OrderNumber <> ta.OrderNumber OR o.FormulaCode <> ta.FormulaCode OR o.FormulaName <> ta.FormulaName OR o.BeginDeliveryDate <> ta.BeginDate) THEN
UPDATE
SET ta.FormulaCode=o.FormulaCode, ta.FormulaName=o.FormulaName
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND o.BeginDeliveryDate >= '12/24/15' THEN
INSERT (OrderNumber, FormulaCode, FormulaName, BeginDate) VALUES (o.OrderNumber, o.FormulaCode, o.FormulaName, o.BeginDeliveryDate);
```

The error I get is:

```
Msg 5315, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.
```

I know that you can use merge by running it on the remote and "pulling" the data in, but that is not an option here because the remote server is a Azure DB and does not have that functionality because I need to ultimately need to run this as a job when I'm done.

Anyone have any ideas or any other options I can try?

Comment: Even if you were able to do this, this will have nasty performance implications. You should make this process asynchronous if possible. SSIS or a staging/queue table?

Comment: I think SSIS is out of the question.  Care to explain the staging/queue table, I'm trying to look it up, but not really finding much.

Comment: Can't you insert your data in a table in the target database (DBSERVER.ft_test2) and then call a stored procedure (target database) to perform the merge? Joining tables over linked servers can be really slow.

Comment: Alexei - Good idea I will try and go down that path.  Not sure why I did not think of it. Thanks!  Yea I read that they can be slow, but I'm never going to be dealing with more then 50 records per query and it only needs to run around 10 times a day so I figured it would be fine.